# How to extract value from list into numeric

Tags: r, lapply, sapply

I want to extract value from list into numeric

This is my list `str(maxenv)`

```
$ x: num [1:36] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
$ y: num [1:36] 157 94.2 75.1 88.7 124
```

I want to get value of `y`

So the result should be

```
y = 157 94.2 75.1 88.7 124
```

I have tried but didnt work

```
sapply(maxenv, '[', 'y')
```

Comment: What about the old fashioned way: `maxenv[["y"]]`

Comment: Thanks you very much, it's work @csgillespie

Comment: If you need to ask this question, I'd advise you to do an R-tutorial. It is very basic, and taking some time to learn things like indexing will make learning R a lot smoother for you.